# Sending value of the value attribute to other php page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm try to send the value from the value attribute in **button** using a form that use the method **POST** in "landlord_home.php". The problem was that when I click on the button to go to the next page which is "edit_post.php", it execute the php validation code in that page and display the validation error in that page.

How can I pass the value to "edit_post.php" without using a form(POST or GET method) or is there any other way?

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $row['property_id'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['username']. '</td>
            <td>' . $row['property_type']. '</td>
            <td>RM' . $row['property_price']. '</td>
            <td>' . $row['address']. '</td>
            <td>' . $row['location']. '</td>
            <td>
              <img src="data:property_type;base64,' .
              $row['property_picture'] .
              '" class="img-thumbnail" width="100" height="100">
            </td>
            <td>' . $row['title'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>
            <td>' . date('F d, Y h:mA', strtotime($row['reg_date'])) . '</td>
            <td>
              <form action="edit_post.php" method="POST">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="edit" value="' .
                $row['property_id'] . '">
                  Edit
                </button>
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="delete" 
                value="'.$row['property_id'] . '">
                  Delete
                </button>
              </form>
            </td>
          </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Above is the code from "landlord_home.php". Below is the part of code that I am talking about from above code.

```
<form action="edit_post.php" method="POST">
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="edit" value="' .
  $row['property_id'] . '">
    Edit
  </button>
  <br>
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="delete" value="' .
  $row['property_id'] . '">
    Delete
  </button>
</form>
```

And below is the code of the next page "edit_post.php"

```
 session_start();
  $user = $_SESSION['username'];
  if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    require('login_tools_landlord.php');
    load();
  }
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Edit Property</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/add_property.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include 'includes/header_landlord.php' ?>
    <div class="container wrapper">
      <div class="text-center title_bar">
        <h3>Fill in your property details</h3>
        <?php
         if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
           require ('core/connect_db.php');
           $errors = array();

           if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {

             $edit = $_POST['edit'];
             $q = "SELECT * FROM property WHERE property_id = '$edit'";
             $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

             $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
             $prop_type = $row['property_type'];
             $price = $row['property_price'];
             $address = $row['address'];
             $location = $row['location'];
             $pic = $row['property_picture'];
             $title = $row['title'];
             $desc = $row['description'];
             $dt = $row['reg_date'];

            if (empty($_POST['property_type'])) {
              $errors[] = 'Choose property type.';
            } else {
              $pr = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['property_type']));
            }

            if (empty($_POST['price'])) {
              $errors[] = 'Enter your property price.';
            } else {
              $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['price']));
            }

            if (empty($_POST['address'])) {
              $errors[] = 'Enter your address.';
            } else {
              $ad = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['address']));
            }

            if (empty($_POST['location'])) {
              $errors[] = 'Choose your location.';
            } else {
              $lo = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['location']));
            }

        // if (empty($_POST['picture'])) {
        //   $errors[] = 'Pick a picture.';
        // } else {
        //   $pc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['picture']));
        // }
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
              if (getimagesize($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']) == FALSE) {
                  $errors[] = "Please select an image.";
              } else {
                $picture = addslashes($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']);
                $name = addslashes($_FILES['picture']['name']);
                $picture = file_get_contents($picture);
                $picture = base64_encode($picture);
              }
            }

            if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
              $errors[] = 'Enter your title.';
            } else {
              $ti = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['title']));
            }

            if (empty($_POST['description'])) {
              $errors[] = 'Enter your description.';
            } else {
              $de = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['description']));
            }

        if (empty($errors)) {
          $qa = "
            UPDATE property
            SET property_type = '$pr', property_price = '$p', address = '$ad',
              location = '$lo', property_picture = '$picture', title = '$ti',
              description = '$de', reg_date = NOW()
            WHERE property_type = '$prop_type', property_price = '$price',
              address = '$address', location = '$location',
              property_picture = '$pic', title = '$title',
              description = '$desc', reg_date = '$dt'
            ";
          $ra = mysqli_query($dbc, $qa);

          if ($ra) {
            echo '<h1 class="sccs_msg">Successful</h1>
                  <p class="sccs_msg">REDIRECTING YOU TO DASHBOARD in 3 SECOND</p>
                  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=landlord_home.php" />';

          }
          mysqli_close($dbc);
          exit();
        } else {
          echo '<h1 class="err_msg">ERROR!</h1>
          <p class="err_msg">The following error(s) occurred:<br>';
          foreach ($errors as $msg) {
            echo "- $msg<br>";
          }
          echo 'Please try again.</p>';
          mysqli_close($dbc);
        }
      }
    }
    ?>

      </div>
      <form method="post" action="edit_post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="property_type">Property Type</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="property_type" id="property_type" 
          value="<?php
            if (isset($_POST['property_type'])) {
              echo $_POST['property_type'];
            }
          ?>">
            <option></option>
            <option>Room</option>
            <option>Whole Unit</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="price">Unit Price(RM)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="unit_price" 
          placeholder="Unit Price" value="<?php
            if (isset($_POST['price'])) {
              echo $_POST['price'];
            }
          ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="address">Address</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="address" id="address" rows="3"
          value="<?php
            if (isset($_POST['address'])) {
              echo $_POST['address'];
            }
          ?>"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="location">Location</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="location" id="location"
          value="<?php
            if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
              echo $_POST['location'];
            }
          ?>">
            <optgroup label="Kuala Lumpur">
              <option></option>
              <option>Puchong</option>
              <option>Salak Selatan</option>
              <option>Segambut</option>
              <option>Sentul</option>
              <option>Seputih</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Selangor">
              <option>Cheras</option>
              <option>Damansara</option>
              <option>Cyberjaya</option>
              <option>Kajang</option>
              <option>Kelana Jaya</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="picture">Picture</label>
          <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="picture"
          id="picture" aria-describedby="fileHelp"
          value="<?php
            if (isset($_POST['picture'])) {
              echo $_POST['picture'];
            }
          ?>">
          <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
            Please provide a photo of your property.
          </small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title"
          placeholder="Post Title" value="<?php
            if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
              echo $_POST['title'];
            }
          ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="description"
          rows="3" value="<?php
            if (isset($_POST['description'])) {
              echo $_POST['description'];
            }
          ?>"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something like you did with `$edit`.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for that reminder. Kinda newbie in php. I still didn't explore php security yet so my code is very vulnerable.

Comment: Being aware of this is a first step towards adopting a discipline where you don't expose yourself to trouble. Often after you write code it has a way of worming its way into production, so it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: @tadman Thank you. Will keep that in mind from now.

Comment: What you're looking for here is to include the value in a query-string parameter if you're okay with using `GET`. `edit_post.php?id=X` is the general form for these. If you're prepared to use a proper development framework with a routing engine these can be part of the URL itself, so `edit_post.php?id=5` becomes `/post/5/edit`. [Laravel](http://laravel.com) is an example of a friendly, powerful framework that handles all of this for you if you use their routing system. Once nice thing about routes is you can change the internals without having to re-write all your page links.

Comment: @tadman Sorry I don't really get that. Can you please explain it more. I'm new in php. Keep in mind that this is just my college final project and will not be posted online.

Comment: Can you make a string of the form `edit_post.php?id=5` and put it in a link? If so, `$_GET[id]` will be `'5'` on the receiving page.

Comment: It's worth noting to never put dangerous actions behind regular `GET` links. Some browsers will aggressively pre-fetch pages and if your "delete record" link is a simple `GET`, goodbye database. I'd strongly recommend using something like Laravel to give your code structure and good examples to work from on how to handle this sort of thing. Any framework will have a convention for doing this consistently.

Comment: @tadman Okey will try that out. Thank you

Comment: @tadman Your solution fixed my validation errors from showing at page load. But when I click on the submit button on "edit_post.php" page it do nothing.

Comment: I can only offer so much advice. I'd recommend boiling this down into two simple problems and break that out as different questions. Keep things bite-sized and you'll get better, more focused advice.

Comment: @tadman Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

> How can I pass the value to "edit_post.php" **without using a form**(POST or GET method) or is there any other way?

I'm not sure to understand what you mean above, unless you wanted to say **without using an *additional visible* form input**.
If so, then the answer is contained in the question: you have merely to add a *hidden* input to your form (and give up buttons value):

```
<form action="edit_post.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="property-id" value=" . $row['property_id'] . '">
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="edit">
    Edit
  </button>
  <br>
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="delete">
    Delete
  </button>
</form>
```

Then in `edit_post.php` you can use `$_POST['property-id']` as you want.

---

BTW I'm a bit surprised looking at your `$qa` query in `edit_post.php`: unless I missed something subtle, its `WHERE` clause is invalid, since it's built like a comma-separated list of condition (while they probably should be ANDed).